# How can I take 1000's of http://, https:// links clickable?

Tags: html

How can I take 1000's of http://, https:// links clickable? I would like to be able to make all these(1) links clickable but it would take a few days to get to them all. Is there a way to put in the syntax required automatically. At the moment it is txt and I know I will have to change that. I'd like if possible for it to all do it every time I add another entry. I have a database. Would it just be easier to link a page to a database and prefix all the links with http:// somehow? I am hopful you kind people will have a fix for me and if you don't then please do suggest other ways to do this. Please understand I have hardly any understanding of coding and such but I do understand basic html. I am ever so sorry to trouble you with what must seem like a basic problem. Thank you ever so much for your help!

Have a wonderful day everyone! Be safe. This(2) is what my database entries look like. I'm awfully sorry for my spelling and grammar.
Also the reason why (2) doesn't have http://'s is because the database does not support the : symbol and instead of a domain it would be http// instead of http://.

- (1) = http://anythingmayhappen.com/list
- (2) = https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZzKS.jpg

Comment: The first link from your question leads to a plain TXT file. It needs to be an HTML file with proper syntax (`<a>` HTML tag)

Comment: I don't see how the question is related to notepad++ or dreamweaver.

Comment: Which database are you using e.g Oracle, MySQL, and etc...?

Comment: @Charles I believe it is mysql. I had a developer set it all up for me but since the time she did it all. She has gone missing from the internet and I have no way to contact her. I am still working on finding the database name and password.  Thanks! Have a wonderful day!

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I put those on as a way to identify which software I have. I will take them off now though :) Sorry for the trouble :) Also I know it's plain text and that will have to be changed. I just didn't want to do anything until I knew what was the best way to do it. Thanks for letting me know though! Have a wonderful day! Be safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can  get the liks from the database using `CONCAT` function:

For example you can do a query like this.

```
SELECT CONCAT ('<a href="http://', link, '">', link, '</a>') FROM links_table;
```

And put the result on a an HTML file in a plain text editor (like notepad ++) and save it with the `html` extension.

To have the propper HTML you should add an HTML header and body. But this would be enought for making the links clickable.

In the plain text editor you can put the a title and the result of the database query within this code to have a basic HTML page with the links:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head> 
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
     <title>Put here the title you want</title>
  </head>
  <body> 
     Put here the result of the SQL Query to the database
  </body>
<html>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Oh thanks! I will check this out! This is really helpful. I have tried to tick it but it wouldn't tick and I should wait to see if it works first anyway. Thank you so much for being so kind.

Comment: I think in your case the SQL query is probably: `SELECT CONCAT ('<a href="http://', link, '">', link, '</a>') FROM links;` but if you edit the question to tell us which database and which tables are you using maybe we can explain better.

Comment: I would first of all like to say I honestly am not trying to be this stupid. it just  kind of happends. Probably thanks to autism! YAY AUTISM! Anyway this is what I put in and I'm pretty sure I've missed something stupid https://i.imgur.com/TWyd3qb.png Please keep in mind I have 0 knowladge with mysql so think when explaining that I'm a real goat without the man part. I have only changed the bit that I thought would 100% have to be there to save confusion. Thank you so much for your kindness. If it helps you can contact me by email and I can send any files that may help you? @pconcepion

Comment: The database is called "flyinggo_lama" I am only inputting to link at the moment but in the future I plan to fill out the description as well, @pconcepion

Comment: You have to run the SQL query ( `SELECT CONCAT ('<a href="http://', link, '">', link, '</a>') FROM links;` )  on the database (this window you show https://i.imgur.com/mJpR4tO.png ) and then copy the results  on the sample html I gave you (substituting the `Put here the result of the SQL Query to the database` whit the result of the query on the database.

Comment: I have removed the s in links because it was returning an error. This is what I get when I quary https://i.imgur.com/wNYP8cf.png. what do I copy? the lines seem too long from the ... at the end of each line to copy like I normally would with text. I do not see any copy box or button. Thank you :)

Comment: I have tried but every time I copy it doesn't copy it all. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you can do something like `SELECT CONCAT ('<a href="http://', link, '">', link, '</a>') FROM links INTO OUTFILE 'path_to_the_file';` to save the query directly on a file.

Comment: I managed to fix the problem of it all not being visable! thanks though. Would this outfile method allow it to update when ever I add a new link?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I got your question right but can't you just loop through the database, add an anchor and save it to a div that is displayed?

Like (pseudocode):

```
for(var i = 0; i < database.length; i++) {
 $("#list").html($("#list").html() + "<li><a href='" + getTheUrlViaSubstring(database[i]) + "'>" + database[i] + "</a><li>");
}
```

Comment: I am not sure that's why I asked haha. I will look into this though and see if I have the knowhow to see if this works :) I am thankful for your guideness and hope you have a great day! Be safe ....man or women..... or goat.